# Access to storage values in Ionic3

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I would like to be able to get the more simplest array of the storage object in **Ionic 3**
I did that already:

```
this.item = Array.of(this.storage.get(‘thestations’));
```

And i get this type of array in the console view of chrome:

```
[t]
    0: t__zone_symbol__state:  true
        __zone_symbol__value  :  Array(1)

0  : {
    id: “3015”,
    name: “Mansle”,
    latitude: “85.878”,
    longitude: “8.17527”,
    numdept: “16”,
    …
  }

length :  1
proto  :  Array(0)
proto  :  Object
length :  1
proto  :  Array(0)
```

I wish to get this values in a simple array

```
{
    id: “3015”,
    name: “Mansle”,
    latitude: “85.878”,
    longitude: “8.17527”,
    numdept: “16”,
    …
  } ?
```

Regards

Frank

Comment: You are using native storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below call. Storage return promise object so you have using `then()`

```
this.storage.get('thestations').then((val) => {
    console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much